# how to connect to flink elasticsearch version 6.2.2 to flink 1.4.1

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-flink

I am using elasticsearch 6.2.2 as sink in flink, but while reading in apache flink documentation, i can see connector for elasticserver version 5.x but no connector for 6.x is mentioned.

Does flink support any connector for elasticsearch 6.x? or should i make any http client and make a post request to create or update new document everytime? or is their any other technique?

Answer (score 0):

Flink 1.4.x does not provide a connector for Elasticsearch 6.x and the included connector only works up to Elasticsearch 5.1.x (due to API breaking changes in Elasticsearch's client in 5.2.x).

There is an open issues in Flink's JIRA to track the progress for Elasticsearch 6.x support [FLINK-8101](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-8101).

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround to @fabian-hueske answer you can do the following:

1) You can write a custom Http sink that sends your data to Elasticsearch using Elasticsearch REST API https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs.html

2) You can also create a custom sink using the following librarie https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s to connect to Elasticsearch over TCP